# How can I create a non-evaluated mapping in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have this function

```
let tid = forkIO $ sequence_ ioOps
let ioOps = take 200 $ cycle $ intersperse (threadDelay (1000000*60*20)) $ mapM putStrLn stoJeLuka
```

and I know it's not pretty but I'm only hacking away.

I'm trying to run a script which at specific periods outputs one of the strings provided in the `stoJeLuka :: [String]`.

My issue was that my `mapM` evaluates the `putStrLn` before I would like it to.
How do I only create a `list :: [IO a]` without evaluating these `putStrLn`'s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapM` is pretty much `sequence . map`, which means that it *will* be evaluated and made into an action.

You want to simply `map putStrLn` - that will create a list of type `[IO ()]` without carrying out the desired action. When you want it to be printed, simply `sequence` that list, or call `foldl (>>) (return ())` on it, like within `mapM_`.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear, because you haven't actually explained what you want the code to do. But something looks fishy. Specifically, `mapM putStrLn stoJeLuka` is an `IO` action that *produces* a list; it's not actually a list. So calling `intersperse` on it will produce a type error. You probably meant to use `map` or `fmap` rather than `mapM`. I'm guessing your code may actually do that already, and you're complaining about when those things get executed relative to some other code you're not showing.

Comment: I have said what I want ti do and there is no other code related to this